# Populate posts with author and display author - mern

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

I am trying to make a relationship between the post and the user/author but I'm struggling to populate the posts with the author and display the author of the post. I can create posts with various fields but how would I populate the author (username) in the post with node and display it in react?

Part of Post schema

```
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema.Types

...

 author: {
          id: { 
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
         username: String
     },
```

controllers/posts.js

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
 const {title, body, date } = req.body
  const post = new Post({title, body, date, author: ........ })
  

  post.save()
  .then(response => {res.send(response)})
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
      })
    }

exports.list = (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
   .populate("author", "_id name")
  .select("-photo")
 .limit(5)
 .exec((err, posts) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } 
     res.send(posts)
  })
}
```

components/CreatePost.js

```
 class CreatePost extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
     
         this.state = {
              title: '',
              body: ''
         }
     }

     changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios({ url: `${API}/new-post`, method: 'POST', data: this.state})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {title, body} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <input type="text" name="title" 
                onChange={this.changeHandler} value={title} />
                <input type="text" name="body"
                onChange={this.changeHandler} value={body}/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CreatePost
```

Comment: Could you post network response of this call? `axios({ url: `${API}/new-post`, method: 'POST', data: this.state})`

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating the author in your `create` controller. Consider the following:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
 const {title, body, date } = req.body
  const post = new Post({title, body, date, author: ........ }).populate('author', '_id name')
```

As you do in the `.list` controller.